JMeter websocket error: WebSocket I/O error: Connection timed out: connect
I am creating a SignalR load test using JMeter
I followed the tutorial here
Note: I am using https for first call and wss for second call
when I run 100 threads all is good, but the moment I increase to 500 or more, 80% test start failing with the messages:
For the http /chat request:
Thread Name: SignalR 1-788
Sample Start:2024-08-15 17:05:10 EEST
Load time:21042
Connect Time:21042
Latency:0
Size in bytes:2908
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:2908
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to xxx.azurewebsites.net:443 [xxx.azurewebsites.net/xxx.xxx.0.xxx] failed: Connection timed out: connect


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

and for the websocket open connection:
Thread Name:SignalR 1-754
Sample Start:2024-08-15 16:38:30 EEST
Load time:21045
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:0
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:0
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):
Response code:Websocket I/O error
Response message:WebSocket I/O error: Connection timed out: connect


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

One very important thing I noticed is that all failed requests has Load time > 20000.
I set http request timeout to 300000 ms
I also set websocket open connection timeouts (connect and read) to 300000
Did not help.
I tried 2 different net wifi speeds (4-6 mbps) and (12-15 mbps)
Then I tried 4g from my mobile as hotspot to my Pc (35-42 mbps)
I turned off firewall and my antivirus
I tried increasing ramp-up time
all give same result....80% of requests fail with the above response.
what is going on?

Well, it indicates that the system under test is overloaded and cannot properly handle 500 concurrent users.

Check system under test configuration, it might be the case the connection pool is exhausted
Check whether the system under test has sufficient resources like CPU, RAM, Network sockets, Disk IO, etc. You can use JMeter PerfMon Plugin for this
Use an APM or a profiler tool to check what is going on under the hood and whether there is a problematic function or inefficient algorithm

